# Getting TypeError: sparse matrix length is ambiguous; use getnnz() or shape[0] while doing multi class classification

Tags: pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn, typeerror, multiclass-classification

```
from sklearn.naive_bayes import CategoricalNB
from sklearn.datasets import make_multilabel_classification
X, y = make_multilabel_classification(sparse = True, n_labels = 15,
return_indicator = 'sparse', allow_unlabeled = False)
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train,X_test,y_train,y_test=train_test_split(X,y,test_size=0.25,random_state=0)
```

I tried using X.todense() but the error is still raised.

```
X_train = X_train.todense()
X_test = X_test.todense()
```

Training on the dataset

```
from skmultilearn.adapt import MLkNN
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
classifier = MLkNN(k=20)
classifier.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

predicting the output of trained dataset.

```
y_pred = classifier.predict(X_test)
accuracy_score(y_test,y_pred)
np.concatenate((y_pred.reshape(len(y_pred),1), y_test.reshape(len(y_test),1)),1)
```

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to get the length from a matrix, which is ambigious:

```
len(y_pred)
```

Your matrix y_pred has the dimension (25,5), as seen with `y_pred.shape`.

So instead of `len(y_pred)`, you could use `y_pred.shape[0]`, which would return 25.

But then you will encounter a problem when you are using `y_pred.reshape(y_pred.shape[0],1)`

**ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 125 into shape (25, 1)**

(previously: `y_pred.reshape(len(y_pred),1)`)

This error makes sense, because you are trying to reshape a matrix with 125 values into a matrix with only 25 values. You need to rethink your code here.